# How to call require for more files in one line?

Tags: requirejs, protractor

I have a protractor test and I made helper js files for each functionality (E.g. login, createObject, logout). 
   These separate js files are called from Test.js (the spec file).
   I want to make the require for all 3 methods in config.js, but in just one call, all my tests contain a lot of helpers/methods files.
I've tried this:

in config.js,

```
onPrepare: function () {
'use strict';
global.Methods = require ('./method1.js' , './method2.js' , './method3.js');
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me if this is possible or if there is a better way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that.. `require()` function takes only one file as argument.  Thanks

Comment: You are mistaken `requireJS` and `commonJS`. The `require()` used in your sample is `commonJS`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the require function only takes one file as an parameter you can put all your methods into one file called actions. This way you only have to make one require call to gain access to all your methods.

```
global.Methods = require('./actions.js');
or even better 
global.Methods = new (require('./actions.js'));
```

Or simply require one file at a time

```
global.Methods1 = require ('./method1.js');
global.Methods2 = require ('./method2.js');
global.Methods3 = require ('./method3.js');
```